# Best way to process a GCS file within Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a PCollection of matched GCS filenames, each of which contains a single compressed JSON blob. What's the best way to read the entire file, decompress it (Gzip format), and JSON decode it?

- TextIO is really close, but reads data per-line.
- GCS API offers an example for [how to read the entire file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted#reading_gcs_data_into_a_byte_array), but it doesn't handle decompression and is leading me to reimplement a lot of core functionality.

Are there any existing APIs and/or examples that can give me a head start? Seems like this would be a pretty common use case.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the question -- ideally, you'd like something like: JsonIO.Read.from(myFileName).withCompressionType(JsonIO.CompressionType.GZIP) -- is that correct?

Comment: Yep, and the file is a GCS object (gs://bucket/file.json.gz).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't natively supported in Dataflow.  To accomplish reading a JSON blob out of a file, you could implement FileBasedSource:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource

If that's enough to get started, we can continue to update this answer with more information.

Comment: Any tips for best way to decompress the contents? Is there a gzip coder, or some such?

Comment: Could you model a solution based on TextIO's handling of GZIP?  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.java